# Confusion between probability density and probability in EM-paper

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm reading about expectation maximization from Dempster et al. and there is one point in the paper I get confused about probability density and probability. Maybe you can clarify this to me. Here is my source (my problem is at page 1):

http://web.mit.edu/6.435/www/Dempster77.pdf

I have sketched a picture from my confusion. It will explain my problem. Thank you for any help :)

[image]

I also get confused about the notion of "**incomplete data**" and "**complete data**". Can someone give me more concrete examples? What is "**incomplete data**" in the real world and what is "**complete data**" in the real world. Examples? When things get too abstract it's nice time to time bring the thought back to ground level :)

Comment: Hallo @jjepsuomi; before posting a more complete answer, I would like to point out that the integral of $f(x|\phi)$ is no probability because...it is no nonnegative number (smaller equal to $1$). It is a function of the realizations $y$, and the parameters $\phi$. This is why it is denoted by $g(y|\phi)$.

Comment: +1 Hey @Avitus and thank you for your help again :) You've been most helpful to me, much obliged :) Hmm..now I got even more confused :D so...$f(x|\phi)$ is not a probability density function? "it is no nonnegative number (smaller equal to 1)" Why? I don't see that stated in the paper? :/ Maybe an example could help? Could you give me a simple example? Doesn't need to be long or anything. Just a concrete example :) Thank you!

Comment: $f(x|\phi)$ is a probability density, this is correct. But $g(y|\phi)$ is no probability, i.e. a real number $p\in[0,1]$. In your notation, $p$ is for example $P(a\leq x\leq b)$. $g$ is another probability density, given by the integral formula. In particular, it is a function of $y$ (variables) and $\phi$ (parameters). I try to read the reference, ok?

Comment: +1 @Avitus okay, thank you! :) sorry if I rushed you. Take your time :) P.S. I only read the first and second page, because I assume always that the material is linear in that sense that you don't have to read from page 10 to understand page 1 :)

Comment: you are a funny dude :) I have added an answer, collecting some info on the paper. I think that looking at the example on pag. 2 could help you with notation.

Comment: +1 @Avitus Thanx xD and you're very good at answering ;) I will look into the example and your answer :) I will comment if I have any trouble with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the above comments, I would like to fix some notation on *complete-incomplete data*, as propoesed in the reference in the OP.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sample spaces and

$$\eta: X\rightarrow Y, x\mapsto \eta(x):=y$$

be a mapping between the two spaces. We refer to $x$ as the complete data (which are not observed directly) and to $y$ to the incomplete data (those which are directly observed). The mapping $\eta$ gives the relationship between what is not observed and what it is. The idea is to be able to reconstruct the density probability

$$g(y|\varphi)$$

of the incomplete data and parameters $\varphi$ (our starting point) as a function of the corresponding density function

$$f(x|\varphi) $$

of the underlying-not directly observed complete data and the parameters $\varphi$.
Such reconstruction is given by the formula

$$g(y|\varphi)=\int_{\mathcal L(y)}f(x|\varphi)dx,~~(*)$$

where the integral is performed on the domain $\mathcal L(y)\subseteq X$ defined through

$$\mathcal L(y)=\{x\in X: \eta(x)=y\}, $$

for all incomplete data $y\in Y$. The domain $\mathcal L(y)$ depends on $y$ itself: then the result of the integration in $(*)$ *must be* a function of $y\in Y$.

In summary, both $g(y|\varphi)$
and $f(x|\varphi)$ are density functions; the integral $(*)$ gives a density function, i.e. $g(y|\varphi)$, and not a probability (i.e. a number $p\in [0,1]$). Probabilities are obtained, for example, by integrals

$$P(a\leq X\leq b)=\int_a^b f_X(r)dr,~~(**)$$

for any the continuous r.v. $X$ with probability density $f_X(r)$. Please note that the integral in $(**)$ is completely different from the one in $(*)$; in $(**)$ we integrate a function $f_X$ of the variable $r$ along $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb R$: the result of such operation is then a scalar, as expected.

- Example at pag. 2 in the original reference: $\eta$ and $\mathcal L(y)$.

In the example at pag. 2 in the original reference, we have

$$\eta: X\rightarrow Y, x\mapsto \eta(x):=y$$

with $\eta(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5):=(x_1+x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$. The domain $\mathcal L(y)$ reads

$$\mathcal L(y)=\{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)\in X: \eta(x)=y\}, $$

for all $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)\in Y$.

Comment: +1 @Avitus Thnx for the answer, one point to clarify: what exactly does complete data and incomplete data mean? Does in this context complete data = "data which is not observed directly", that is e.g. we know $y = 2x + 1$, $y_1 = 5, y_2 = 3, y_3 = 8, ...$, but we don't know $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$ etc.? Lets say you have an apple tree with apples of different color (green ones, red ones, a bit yellow ones etc.) Can you come up with a physical example what incomplete and complete data would mean in this scenario with respect to the theory we are discussing here ;D Hope I'm not making you crazy ;D

Comment: I just want to make the point home x) You know when we discuss about complete data and incomplete data intuitively I think that complete data would mean e.g. in the words of statistics the full population (e.g. all the people in the world) and incomplete data means a sample data (all the people in China), because its incomplete, we don't HAVE all the data. Hope my questions aren't silly, I just get drowned in abstractness sometimes and I'm very specific person, I can't do anything with abstract ideas, I need details x)

Comment: In the example of pag 2 "incomplete" means that the sampling of $y$ does not recognize the presence of $5$ (instead of $4$) categories of animals. The sampling of $x$ (which has $5$ components) recognizes the correct number of categories. In the abstract of the reference it is written that the paper contains several examples of "incomplete data". I found also this reference: ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1509.pdf. I hope it helps!